# What all was on Max's back?

Tags: mad-max-fury-road

At one point in *Mad Max: Fury Road* they tattoo some things on Max's back.  I noticed "O negative - universal doner" and "High Octane," but there were other writings as well.

What else was on Max's back?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From a [post in Reddit - /r/movies by user, BigTimStrange](https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/2bvbb7/mad_max_fury_road_comic_con_footage/cj9dtw2?context=3):

> They're making Max their slave. It lists his physical condition, his
>   compatibility as a donor and the circumstances surrounding his
>   capture.
>
> - No lumps No B
> - Two good eyes No
> - Piss (OK) Genitals intact
> - Multiple scars Heals fast
> - O-NEGATIVE HI OCTANE
> - UNIVERSAL DONOR
> - Lone Road Warrior Rundown
> - the Powder Lakes (NO)
> - No supplies
> - PSYCHOTIC
> - muzzled...

Even most of them can be clearly read from picture below

[image]

Comment: very nice.  I'm wondering if there's any info on the parts that are cut off. such as the "No B" part  and the "Two good eyes No" part.

Comment: @DForck42 i also wondered for that part but got no success in getting that yet.

Comment: Can you edit so it's clear which lines are complete and which are truncated? e.g. `No lumps no B[...]`

Answer (score 34):

There is a relevant concept art as shown in Abbie Bernstein's book *The Art of Mad Max: Fury Road*:

[image: Here is the original artwork]

This includes every line on Max's back.  The only change is the O-plus which becomes O-negative in the film.

> Day 12045 - ht 10 hands - 180 pounds
>   No Name
>   No lumps No Bumps Full life Clear
>   Two good eyes No Busted limbs
>   Piss OK Genitals intact
>   Multiple Scars Heals fast
>   O-PLUS HI-OCTANE
>   UNIVERSAL DONOR
>   Lone Road Warrior Rundown
>   on the Powder Lakes V8
>   No guzzoline No supplies
>   ISOLATE PSYCHOTIC
>   Keep Muzzled

Comment: this is amazing.  i've got a 100 rep bounty awaiting you.

Comment: @Dforck42 you can also switch the accepted answer to this one with the green tick so people googling this question see this first

Comment: This is definitely the better answer.